# Get Context in fragment from Custom Aler Dialog Class android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-context

I am writing a class for Alert dialog which I want to use in my Fragment Class.I have implemented AdapterView.OnitemClickListener on this class. I have declare private fields for title,context, items, requestcode, listener. I created one constructor. Now I want to call this class and want to set different types of string for different purpose. But I am getting error which declaring the constructor. I would like to know how can I call this constructor here in fragment class. My code for Alert Dialog Class is

```
public class Alert extends Dialog implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

public interface OnDialogItemClickListener {
    void onDialogItemClick(int requestCode, int position,String item);
}

private String title;
private Context context;
private String[] items;
private int requestcode;
private OnDialogItemClickListener listener;

public Alert(Context context, String title, String[] items, int requestcode, OnDialogItemClickListener listener) {
    super(context,R.style.DialogTheme);
    this.title = title;
    this.items = items;
    this.requestcode = requestcode;
    this.listener = listener;

}
private TextView textView;
private ListView listView;
private Button cancel;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_alertlist_contact);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.first_alertlist_textstyle,android.R.id.text1, items);
    textView.setText(title);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    listener.onDialogItemClick(requestcode,i, adapter.getItem(i));
    dismiss();
}
```

}

My MainFragment Class is

```
 public class MainFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
 private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SECOND = 2;
 private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FIRST = 1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    //registerForContextMenu(btn);
    Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            showFirstDialogwithList();
            break;
           .............
            break;
    }

}

private void showFirstDialogwithList() {
    String[] companyName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.company_name);

 // I am getting error in this line
    Alert alert=new Alert(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Contact", companyName,REQUEST_CODE_FIRST,getActivity());
    alert.show();
```

Comment: just give `getActivity()`

Comment: @MohammedFarhan it shows this cannot be applied

Comment: post your logcat here

Comment: if your api is 23 and above  try giving `getContext()`

Comment: use only getActivity() instead of getActivity.getApplicationContext()

Comment: it shows error for the last context. where I use listener in the alert Class

Comment: @Pallavi Tapkir  it depends on minSDK too. If its above or equal to 23 then `getContext()` must work and if its below then `getActivity()` must work.

Comment: Ya. have you seen my Alert class. where in Context I use OnDialogItemClickListener listener. In substitute of that what can I sue in fragment class

Comment: check if your fragment support library is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: yes I ahve checked this is android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: send view as a parameter in your switch case to your method like this `showFirstDialogwithList(view)` and In that method in place of Context write `view.getContext` this must work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Alert alert=new Alert(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Contact", companyName,REQUEST_CODE_FIRST,**getActivity()**);
```

You are passing your activity context as a last parameter for listener.

Simply pass `this` keyword here and make your fragment implement that callback.

```
Alert alert=new Alert(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Contact", companyName,REQUEST_CODE_FIRST,this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fragment activity context instead of getActivity().getApplicationContext().

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        Activity a;

        if (context instanceof Activity){
            a=(Activity) context;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this line

```
Alert alert=new Alert(getView().getContext(),"Contact",companyName,REQUEST_CODE_FIRST,getActivity());
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

## write under code in Your CoreApplication.java

step1)
public class CoreApplication extends Application {

private static CoreApplication instance;
..
}

step2)
onCreate(){
....
instance = this;

}

step3 )add this method()

public static CoreApplication getGlobalApplicationContext() {

```
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this application does not
```

inherit GlobalApplication");
        }

```
    return instance;
```

## }

Step4)
call this method of Application  in Your Fragment.class

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getGlobalApplicationContext());